# Unhandled exception occured when clicks ok,cancel or close button on a dialog which is in maximised state

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, activex

Unhandled exception occured when I click OK, Cancel or Close button on a dialog window, which is in maximised state. It's working fine in minimised state.

I created a sample dialog:

**x.cpp**

```
CSampleDlg dlg;
dlg.CreateModal( WS_EX_WINDOWEDGE|WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT, strTitle,
                 WS_POPUPWINDOW | WS_CAPTION | WS_THICKFRAME, 0,0,340,280, this);
```

Then this sample dialog in turn creates SampleSearch dialog using a ActiveX control "SampleActivx.ocx"

```
SampleSearch sSearch ( IDD_SEARCH_DIALOG, (this->ContinueModal()) ? this :NULL ); 

sSearch.DoModal();
```

While clicking OK, Cancel or Close button on this SampleSearch dialog it will crash in **maximised** state. But it's working fine in **minimised** state. Also it's crashing after repositioning of this dialog.

**Callstack**

Its crashing in GetDefBtnCode.

```
mfc100!COleControlSite::GetDefBtnCode
mfc100!_AfxCheckDefPushButton
mfc100!COccManager::IsDialogMessageA
mfc100!CWnd::IsDialogMessageA
mfc100!CWnd::PreTranslateInput
mfc100!CDialog::PreTranslateMessage
PVsampleAppT!CSampleDlg::PreTranslateMessage
mfc100!CWnd::WalkPreTranslateTree
mfc100!AfxInternalPreTranslateMessage
mfc100!CWinThread::PreTranslateMessage
mfc100!AfxPreTranslateMessage
mfc100!AfxInternalPumpMessage
mfc100!CWnd::RunModalLoop
mfc100!CDialog::DoModal
PVsampleAppT!CCDialog::DoModal
```

Is this issue related to parent window's OnPaint(), onCtlColor()?

Comment: Where does it crash? Show the call stack.

Comment: Please edit your question and don't post that as a comment.

Comment: Probbaly the `this` pointer is NULL or garbage in `COleControlSite::GetDefBtnCode`. It's very hard to remote debug this without more information. Once it has crashed try to walk up the call stack and look at the MFC sources.